# Href tag not working in chrome but working in other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm working on designing website but facing a issue that href # tags are not working in chrome but working in firefox

```html
<ul class="navigation" style="margin-top: 75px;">
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-2">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-4">Products</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-5">Clients</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-6">Team</a></li>
   <li><a class="scroll-to" href="#section-7">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


<section id="section-1" class="banner-container color-light center nav-trigger">
```

I am not sure where its going wrong

Comment: not working mean what exactly it suppose to do?

Comment: @brkwhen I click on section 1 link it should navigate to the selected secion but it doesnt do it chrome but in other browsers it does.

Comment: Must be something else going wrong probably related to some javascript. This is extremely basic functionality in all browsers

Comment: @charlietfl I tried checking it in Developer Tools but still no luck

Comment: Are you sure Chrome doesn't simply have a larger window, so that section-1 is visible when you click the link? Then it wouldn't scroll.

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Jigna, did you see the answers below?  The only thing wrong with your example is that you seem to have left out the content and closing of the `section` tag.  You can see in my code below that this does indeed function as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine for me in Chrome 62.  Are you closing your section tag? Are you sure there is enough height that it would actually scroll?

```css
section {
   padding: 100px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#section-1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-5">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-6">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-7">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<section id="section-1">Home</section>
<section id="section-2">About Us</section>
<section id="section-4">Products</section>
<section id="section-5">Clients</section>
<section id="section-6">Team</section>
<section id="section-7">Contact Us</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try follow this.
https://www.gregoryvarghese.com/chrome-anchor-link-not-working-fix/

```
$(function() {
   $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough height for each div so that page can scroll. Without page scroll you can't see changes, because nothing wrong with your code.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#section-1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-2">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-4">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-5">Clients</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-6">Team</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-7">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-1">Home</section>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-2">About Us</section>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-4">Products</section>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-5">Clients</section>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-6">Team</section>
<section style="height:500px" id="section-7">Contact Us</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a bug in certain versions of Chrome, this workaround did the trick for me, good luck! -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
    if (window.location.hash && isChrome) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            window.location.hash = "";
            window.location.hash = hash;
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the `href` that redirected to pages with hashtags, so I did this workaround:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])', function(e) {
    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('http') > -1 && /chrome/i.test( navigator.userAgent) ){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        window.location.reload();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a complicated and very specific solution that is not clear when it might work. You need to include some sort or explanation or analysis especially when this answer is vastly different to others offered for this question.